# How to force browsers to send input type=number value as is?

Tags: html, input, localization

When I enter e.g. 47,5 in an input type="number" field, my browser (Firefox) automatically converts it to 47.5 when sending the form to the server. (My client culture uses a decimal comma.) I would like it to send the value as is (with a decimal comma) because it would be more convenient to deal with just a user-specified culture rather than a mixture of user and 'default' culture. How can I do this?

Comment: So what do you do when calculating with numbers? If you really want to force it, use `type=text`

Comment: Since the format will depend on the locale of the browser, you don't know how exactly the browser will send it. No, it actually is a good thing that the value is normalised to a predictable format. You always have to format numeric values specifically the way you want them on output.

Comment: @deceze It should depend on the locale of the browser but it seems to be the opposite. For my locale the correct format is 47,5 (and Firefox does not accept 47.5) but then it is converted to 47.5 when the form is sent.

Comment: Yes. The browser UI will adapt to your (the browser's user) locale (,). The *data* sent to the server will always be "programming language" format, which is English (.).

Answer (score 0):

In latest editions of firefox and chrome if you have specified 'type' attribute as number, it will indicate an error on entering the value as 47,5 or 47.5

> We cannot control the client environment

There are cases where apostrophe is also used.
As lumio specified you can use **type="text"** and parse on the server side.

Comment: I believe there is no such thing as type=integer, only type=number. You are right about the client environment, and I want the browser to respect it rather than make any conversions on its own.